# ClassCircularityError is thrown when getCanonicalName

Tags: java, classloader

**Exception stacks.**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCircularityError: 
plugins/agents/Agent
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1085)
        at java.lang.Class.getCanonicalName(Class.java:1169)
        at agents.loader.AgentLoader.getPluginAgentFromCache(AgentLoader.java:288)
        at compiler.AgentCompiler.main(AgentCompiler.java:365)
```

Below is the code which cause the error. It's very strange if I change the getCanonicalName to getName then everything is fine. These loaded classes are loaded with customized ClassLoader. like `cl = defineClass(name, byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);`

```
public Class getPluginAgentFromCache(String name)
{
    if (_loadedClasses == null)
        return null;

    Iterator <Class> iter = _loadedClasses.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        Class c=iter.next(); 
        if (c.getCanonicalName().equals(name))
            return c;
    }

    return null;        
}
```

Any one can tell me why getCanonicalName here will throw this error?
(JDK 1.6.0_20)

**UPDATE**
After some research, I find that when you define the class you must load the its parent class first. But it's hard. When I write to the binary, they are just ordered
by the sequence in the file folder. So when I load them, they will not order by the class
hieriarchy. It's a bit annoying here.For now I just loop the classes , then load the error class again. This is workaround but not a good one.

Comment: ClassCircularityError is thrown by the JVM not getCanonicalName(). According to the API it gets thrown when the JVM detects a circularity in the superclass hierarchy of the class being loaded. Can you show the definitions of the classes you are loading?

Comment: @Hunter I find another way. I can also resolve this problem. That is to put the parentClass of class which cause this error into the same folder. Also use the same classLoader to load it. Then it's fixed. But does it mean I must use the same classLoader to load its parentClass?

Comment: You know your in for a special day when the first Google hit of your Java error is a bug report to Sun.

Comment: @Perception - isn't that from 2002? Also it says that it was fixed in the description.

Comment: somehow you have managed to define a class as being its own superclass. At least that is what is supposed to cause this error.

Comment: @Hunter - from 2006 actually. I think I should have put a smiley face after my comment :)

Comment: I must not be seeing the same bug report, can you link it?

Comment: The class I have defined is not special, but extend an abstract parent class. My guess is JVM cannot find its parent class loaded by another class loader.So JVM linked its parent class to itself?

Comment: Clark, we need more infos : 1) what is the structure of the classes 2) how are classloaders involved . Tampering with classloaders can cause the JVM to detect strange class errors.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why I hit this issue is I am trying to do something JVM not allowed.
I am loading one child class using a custom classloader, but load the parent class using another classloader. This will cause issue when you call  getCanonicalName, I guess this time, JVM will
try to find its parent class, but it failed due to the parent class is loaded by another classloader.
So this exception is thrown.

What I did to fix it, is to put all the parent class(Except the Object class:-)) and the child class to be loaded by the same classloader and interface doesn't need to be loaded by same classloader. About the loading order,
I solved it by adding a findClass method, in this method, it will look for the dependency class by this custom `findClass()` method. Before calling `findClass(),` i will firstly look for the dependency class by the parent classloader.

The call sequence of this classloader is custom classloader `loadClass()` => super (webapp's classloader) `loadClass()`=> `findClass()` method
webapp's classloader is set by the constructor of  custom classloader.

So everything is resolved now.